# Add Error on standard list view

Tags: validation, dml, error-messages

does someone know how to show an error in an object's listview after a dml operation?

I have written a simple trigger that prevents user to delete closed opportunity

```
List<Opportunity> opportunities = [select Id, isClosed from Opportunity where id IN: Trigger.oldMap.keySet()];

for (Opportunity opp : opportunities)
    if((opp.IsClosed ) opp.addError('Closed opportunities cannot be deleted');
```

It works, but obviously the error message is displayed just in the record detail page. If I try to delete a record from the list view (that it's right what I need) I get:
**Validation Errors While Saving Record(s)
There were custom validation error(s) encountered while saving the affected record(s). The first validation error encountered was "Apex trigger......"**

Is there a way to solve this issue without writing a custom visualforce page?
Thank you

Comment: There's an `<apex:messages>` and an `<apex:pageMessages>`. Each has slightly different behavior. Using [Layout Page](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wZkUEAU) from the App Exchange, you should be able to convert the original Standard Page Layout to VF to see which it uses and try using the other. See the [Apex Code Developer's Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index.htm) to understand the difference between the two along with the flags available.

Comment: when I've had this issue, and assuming, the deletion is for a single record, I overrode the standard Delete button with a VF page that does the delete action and hence can display the pageMessage